# Powershell pipeline both remove-item and call function

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I have a powershell script that I use to clean up a build area before fetching files from SVN again. I want to improve logging by keeping a record of what was cleaned up.

```
     Get-ChildItem .\ _
    -Include bin,obj,Debug,ipch,Resources _
    -Exclude "*.png","*.bmp","*.jpg","*.htm*","*.xml","*.fl*","*.css" _
    -Recurse _
   | foreach ($_) { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse}
```

What I would would like to insert here is some type of Format-Table for the foreach process to get the fullname property to output to $bldLog. I have a function that formats a message for the build log with a date time stamp so I just call WriteToLog $msg -STATUS 'INFORMATION'

I have been trying to wrack my brain around this for a couple of days now to get both writeToLog and to get Remove-Item in a pipleLine but without success. Is such a process possible or do I just forget the pipeline and go oldschool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
   Get-ChildItem .\ -Include bin,obj,Debug,ipch,Resources -Exclude "*.png","*.bmp","*.jpg","*.htm*","*.xml","*.fl*","*.css" -Recurse | foreach { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse; WriteToLog $msg -STATUS 'INFORMATION' }
```

Comment: Actually a slight modification worked. WriteToLog $_.FullName. I forgot that I could have multiple commands on a single line with the semicolon separator. Thanks.